# jQuery: adding <tr> in wrong order (desc)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to add new a new `<tr>` into a `<table>`, but the elements are adding in the wrong order (desc). I always want to add the new `<tr>` below.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="b1">add element</button>
<form>
<table id="table">
    <thead>  
        <tr>
            <th>Element:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>  
    </tbody>  
</table>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var i=0;
$('#b1').click(function() {
    $("#table > tbody:last").after('<tr><td>Element' + i + '</td></tr>');
i++;
});
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleus/wzbyQ/)**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just change `after` to `append`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `append()` method:

```
var i=0;
$('#b1').click(function() {
    $("#table > tbody").append('<tr><td>Element' + i + '</td></tr>');
i++;
});
```

Comment: I don't think you should append to the last element, I think you should append to the tbody

Comment: The should really only be one `<tbody>` element, so the `:last` is somewhat redundant.